# can I get profile picture of friends in facebook for my iphone app

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I want to use profile picture of friends in my iphone app,ya facebook provides fbconnect for iphone but is possible to get profile pictures of all friends later used in my iphone app

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get images
Please check [facebook api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)

Just pass the appropriate parameters to you query and get the response

Comment: and for getting the images of the user's friend just pass the uid as well